# RxJava2 wrapper for Firebase Firestore without switching threads?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a reactive observable for Firebase Firestore calls.
I'm facing a threading issue. I'm using rxjava2 to handle threads and I don't want Firestore API to do that for me. It seems like Firestore calls are async, thus `OnSuccess` method is getting called on the main thread

Here is a simple example that showcases the issue:

```
Single<Integer> firestoreSingle = Single.create(emitter -> {
   Log.d("TAG", Thread.currentThread().getName()); // -> RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 Thread
   CollectionReference collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test_collection");
   collectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
       Log.d("TAG",Thread.currentThread().getName()); // -> MAIN THREAD
       List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
       emitter.onSuccess(documentSnapshotList.size());
   }).addOnFailureListener(emitter::onError);
});

firestoreSingle
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(howManyDocs -> {
    Log.d("TAG",Thread.currentThread().getName()); // -> MAIN THREAD
    Log.d("TAG","How many docs: " + howManyDocs);
});
```

Of course, I could add `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` to the reactive stream, but then I would not necessarily get the results on the same thread as the one I initially subscribed on.

I don't want the results neither in the main thread, nor in a different thread that the one I subscribed on.

**Is there a way to query Firestore synchronously?** How would you solve this issue?

Comment: You can use `final Task<T> task = collectionRef.get(); Tasks.await(task);` then you can access the task synchronously i.e `if(task.isSuccessful()) { .. } else { .. }`

Comment: Indeed, that is correct, @MarkKeen. Thank you. You can add this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer that @MarkKeen suggested in the comment but for reference if you want to stick with RxJava, you can always call the method `.blockingGet()` to, as it suggests, block until a value is emitted.